# Evaluate $\int \dfrac{x^2}{(x\cos x-\sin x)(x\sin x+\cos x)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int \dfrac{x^2}{(x\cos x-\sin x)(x\sin x+\cos x)}dx$$

My attempts is as follows:-

Integrating by parts:-

$$\dfrac{1}{(x\cos x-\sin x)(x\sin x+\cos x)}\cdot\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{1}{3}\int\dfrac{x^3\left(-x\sin x(x\sin x+\cos x)+x\cos x(x\cos x-\sin x)\right)}{(x\cos x-\sin x)^2(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx$$

$$\dfrac{1}{(x\cos x-\sin x)(x\sin x+\cos x)}\cdot\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{1}{3}\int\dfrac{x^3\left(-x^2\sin^2x-x\sin x\cos x-x\cos x\sin x+x^2\cos^2x\right)}{(x\cos x-\sin x)^2(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx$$

$$\dfrac{1}{(x\cos x-\sin x)(x\sin x+\cos x)}\cdot\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{1}{3}\int\dfrac{x^3\left(x^2\cos2x-x\sin 2x\right)}{(x^2\cos x\sin x+x\cos^2x-x\sin^2x-\sin x\cos x)^2}dx$$

$$\dfrac{1}{(x\cos x-\sin x)(x\sin x+\cos x)}\cdot\dfrac{x^3}{3}-\dfrac{1}{3}\int\dfrac{x^3\left(x^2\cos2x-x\sin 2x\right)}{(\cos x\sin x(x^2-1)+x\cos 2x)^2}dx$$

I thought numerator and denominator in the second would be quite similar, but its not, so I was not able to proceed from here.

Any directions?

Answer (score 2):

The integrand is $\frac{x\cos x}{x\sin x+\cos x}-\frac{-x\sin x}{x\cos x-\sin x}$. In the numerator of the first fraction, add and subtract the $\sin x$ and in the second -- $\cos x$.

Answer (score 1):

It's just $$\ln\left|\frac{x\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{x\cos{x}-\sin{x}}\right|+C,$$ which we can get by the definition of the integral.

Comment: why how did you get this?

Comment: @user3290550 I took a derivative. Also we can use a substitution $\frac{x\sin{x}+\cos{x}}{x\cos{x}-\sin{x}}=t,$ but I did not make it so.

Comment: Actually, in the last case we obtain: $dt=\frac{x^2}{(x\cos{x}-\sin x)^2}dx$ and from here we can get the answer.